# Reverse engineering a PID controllers parameters

Tags: control-theory

In an attempt to copy an existing PID controller, I wish to identify the active PID controllers parameters.

I found this formula for discrete PID controllers, like the one I want to build.

$$ u(k) = u(k-1) + K_{R} \cdot \left(1+ \frac{T_{0}}{2 \cdot T_{I} }+ \frac{T_{D}}{T_{0}}\right) \cdot e(k) -K_{R} \cdot \left(1 -\frac{T_{0}}{2 \cdot T_{I}  } +\frac{2 \cdot T_{D}}{ T_{0}} \right) \cdot e(k-1) + K_{R} \cdot \frac{T_{D}}{T_{0}} \cdot e(k-2) $$
where

- $u(k)$ is the control variable
- $u(k-1)$ is the previous control
  variable
- $K_{R}$ is the gain factor
- $T_{0}$ is the sampling time
- $T_{I}$ is the integral time
- $T_{D}$ is the derivative time
- $e(k)$ is the error

To identify the right parameters  $T_{I}$,  $T_{D}$, and $K_{R}$ for the right sampling time $T_{0}$ I could just analyse the data, find the values for the error and the control variable with a sampling time in between, solve the equation, and then I'd have the parameters. However, the sampling time in between data measurements is inconsistent, so I don't really know how to calculate this.

If, for example, the data would be as follows

- Second = 0, control variable = 50, error = 10
- Second = 15, control variable = 55, error = 8
- Second = 18, control variable = 56, error = 7

How can I solve this equation for $T_{I}$, $T_{D}$ and $K_{R}$ ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why is the sampling time changing? This makes things, especially concerning stability, way harder. For example, you can probably not use the formula anymore you are stating for PID controllers... In my experience, while there might be good reasons why the sampling time should change, most often a changing sampling time points to something fishy going on...

Comment: My understand is this: The sampling time is inconsistent in the data, because the error measurements are taken inconsistently (data is batched and sent once a memory limit has been reached on the local device ... thousands of measurements are taken on location. Just 1 (most recent) value per sensor is sent). Once the error has been received in the cloud, a new control value is calculated (also in the cloud) and sent back to the device on location.

Sadly I cannot actually log onto the cloud and go through the code that's implemented there.

Comment: Ever thought about skipping the cloud and doing everything locally? Also, it might be simpler to simply implement a new PID controller...locally...like a continuous one because you can now use the 1000s of measurements. Try 5 for the P part and 0 for the other two. When this is working, adjust the I part until you get rid of constant errors in decent time. Keep the D part at 0 because you this is the right thing to do in 99% of the time...

Comment: Yes, the problem is, that the process needs to be scaleable. I.e., I want to implement predictive methods to existing systems, and basically just need to "copy" the existing controllers and manipulate the reference variable. Since this would affect hundreds of feedback control loops, parameterizing everything manually is not really an option. Copying existing controllers and then maybe use adaptive tuning ... that would be ideal

Comment: AFAIU, you have some black-box PID controller. Is it possible for you to simply make up error signals, send them to the controller and measure its response? If so, send the error signal $e(t)=0$ to it until $u(t)$ is approximately constant. Then, switch to $e(t)=100$ or so and measure the response (i.e. $u(t)$). After 3 or 4 time points, the dynamics of $u(t)$ will be determined by the integral part of the controller ($u(t)$ should increase linearly in time, and the slope tells you the value of $T_I$). With that knowledge, you can do similar experiments to determine the other to parts.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are trying to do. If you want to control a system with a controller in the cloud it is called "networked control systems" and there is a huge literature about the topic. If you want to identify an existing controller parameters that is designed to work locally then $T_0$ shouldn't be different between calculations.

Comment: @obareey There is an existing controller that is operated from the cloud. I want to adapt the existing controller by adding some functionality to its logic, but want to use the existing PID parameters, which is why I need to identify them.